# Matching values in two columns mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

Trying to match two columns in same table.  Would like to see that the output of one device feeds input of another.  Here is a sample of the data.  I know the formatting is bad but I did try!  There are four columns.

```
name    output_ip   input_ip    service  
s101    69.255.255.12   192.168.1.2 apple  
s101    69.255.255.12   192.168.1.3 orange  
s102    69.252.102.102  192.168.1.4 grape  
s102    69.252.102.102  192.168.1.5 kiwi  
s103    10.89.96.102    192.168.1.6 strawberry  
s103    10.89.96.102    192.168.1.7 banana  
s104    10.252.36.21    192.168.1.8 pear  
s104    10.252.36.21    192.168.1.9 plum  
r101    192.168.0.23    69.255.255.12   
r101    192.168.0.23    69.255.255.12   
r102    192.168.0.24    69.252.102.102  
r102    192.168.0.24    69.252.102.102  
r103    192.168.0.25    10.89.96.102    
r103    192.168.0.25    10.89.96.102    
r104    192.168.0.26    10.252.36.21    
r104    192.168.0.26    69.255.255.12
```

Would like output like this

```
s101 r101 apple 69.255.255.12   
s101 r101 orange 69.255.255.12   
s102 r102 grape 69.252.102.102   
S102 r102 kiwi 69.252.102.102   
S103 r103 strawberry 10.89.96.102   
S103 r103 banana 10.89.96.102   
S104 r104 pear 10.252.36.21   
S101 r104  69.255.255.12
```

Comment: So you are wanting to see if the output is the same as the input?

Comment: Yes, like s101's output_ip is the input ip for r101 so I need to match those two columns.

Comment: So in the output of the query I need the name and the name of the device with the matching ip.  To start out I just tried some stuff like select name, output_ip, service where output_ip = input_ip but that yielded nothing.  Messed with some sub-queries and I failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what is the criteria to match the data.

My best guess is that you need to join the table with itself, assuming the table is named `data`:

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    r.name,
    s.service,
    s.output_ip
FROM
    data AS s
    JOIN data AS r ON s.output_ip = r.input_ip
GROUP BY
    s.name, r.name, s.output_ip. s.service
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that tomorrow when I get back to the db.  That looks similar to other posts I was looking through today when trying to find an answer.  I am just not familiar with what you are doing with the s.name and r.name.  That is the part that confuses me and I would like to learn more about.

Comment: it is called a "join". Imagine the table being a hat and each row being a piece of paper with the data. Now take another hat with the exact same papers there and pair up the papers from one hat with the others that match the condition in the `ON` clause (that is almost the same as a `WHERE`). The `AS r` and `AS s` parts are just the names of the hats, they are normally not needed unless you want a quick or shorter name for a table or you have the same table twice (in which case you must rename at least one of them to prevent ambiguities)

Comment: Thanks for the real world analogy.  That helps.  I tried to run that query and it eventually gave me an out of memory error.  The table has 170,000 rows and the data set above leaves out many of the columns.

Comment: There are two possible explanations for running out of memory with 170000 rows: a) the DB server has __very__ little memory, b) the data that you have needs more logic to match-up one row with the corresponding one. I would say it is the latter. The way a JOIN works, is that if multiple rows from one table make the `ON` condition true, you will end up with that many rows. In the query I provided, if you have 3 rows with `output_ip` A and 100 rows with `input_ip` A, you will end up with 300 rows in the result. You obviously need to restrict the `ON` condition even further, but we need more data

Comment: That is why my answer starts with: _I am not 100% sure what is the criteria to match the data_